# Output shell command in python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

```
def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return p.communicate()
```

On running :

```
   command = ("git clone " + repo).split()
    run_command(commmnd)
```

Everything is working.But when i try to run multiple commands i got an error.

```
command = ("git clone www.myrepo.com/etc:etc && cd etc && git stash && git pull).split()
run_command(command)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running shell command from Python and capturing the output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-from-python-and-capturing-the-output)

Comment: what is the question? What is wrong? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead?

Comment: I wanted to run multiple commands in one line and store the output into a variable.I don't understand why so many downvotes ? I understand that is a questioan similar about outputing shell commands . but i need to run multiple commands and output into a variable, to later display the output into a django app. ok ?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`subprocess.check_output()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) with the `shell=True` option, but heed the security warning re untrusted inputs if it applies to you.

```
import subprocess

command = 'git clone www.myrepo.com/etc:etc && cd etc && git stash && git pull'
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    print("subprocess failed with return code {}".format(exc.returncode))
    print("message: {}".format(exc.message))
```

After this `output` contains the combined stdout of the executed processes, if it was successful. Otherwise you need to handle a [CalledProcessError](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.CalledProcessError) exception.

Alternatively, if you can not guarantee that the command strings are secure, you can perform each command in turn, progressing to the next command only if the current command's return code is 0 i.e. `CalledProcessError` is not raised.

```
import subprocess
import shlex

command = 'git clone www.myrepo.com/etc:etc && cd etc && git stash && git pull'
output = []
try:
    for cmd in command.split('&&'):
        output.append(subprocess.check_output(shlex.split(cmd)))
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as exc:
    print("{!r} failed with return code {}".format(' '.join(exc.cmd), exc.returncode))
else:
    print(''.join(output))
```

While this is more secure with regard to shell command injection, it is still possible for sensitive arguments to be sniffed by other users for example with `ps`.

Comment: with the shell=True , everything works fine .. but this is a very insecure

Comment: @RusMine: if you don't use untrusted input to construct `command` then why do you think `shell=True` is "very insecure" compared to running similar commands manually?

Comment: It can be insecure if you do not control the strings comprising the command, or the command line arguments are sensitive in some way, e.g. contains a key, password, credit card etc. Otherwise it should be OK.

Comment: many thanks for your answers :) . but can you tell me the difference between subprocess.Popen and subprocess.check_output ? because adding shell=True on my script ,everything seems to work